# Is it possible that add orderer to existing etcd raft ordering organization in hyperledger fabric v2?

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric

I try to build some hyperledger fabric v2 networks with multi host(3 different local pc). And I want to add orderer to existing orderer organization in other pc.

Is it possible that add orderer to existing etcd raft ordering organization in hyperledger fabric v2?

I've searched, but I haven't found suitable examples or methods.

I tried that add orderer’s cert and port, etc, like adding new organization.

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/channel_update_tutorial.html

But I think my problem is slightly different this tutorial, because it is adding organization, not adding orderer or peers to existing organization.

If is it possible, then could you tell me hint or some referencable site, and so on?